# mongoose filter by populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to filter data by related schema

this is my current code

```
const questions = await UserQuestionSet.find({username:req.user},{ username: 1, totalScore:1,complete:1 })
.populate({
  path: 'finalQuestionSet',
  //match: { active:true },
   select: 'title fromDate toDate allowBack active showResults'
}).lean()
```

but I want get all the question if the finalQuestionSet.active is true

How can I do it?

thanks!

Comment: You'll have to write an aggregation pipeline with `$lookup`.

Comment: the lookup get the related data as array, this is not the same as populate with one to one relation

Comment: Yeah, but populate get executed after the filters, you can't filter docs afterwards, $lookup gives you this functionality

Comment: Can you show your schema?

Answer (score 0):

To filter `UserQuestionSet` based on a condition on the populated `finalQuestionSet`, you can use the Mongoose populate() and find() methods with query conditions:

simple use filter() function.

```
 const questions = await UserQuestionSet.find({username:req.user},{ 
 username: 1, totalScore:1,complete:1 })
.populate({
   path: 'finalQuestionSet',
   select: 'title fromDate toDate allowBack active showResults'
 }).lean();
 // add below line
 questions.filter((q) => q?.active !== null)
```

I am sure this will help you